# PHP array variable Null in WP Ajax Function?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to pass a query generated multidimensional array into a wp_ajax_ function.

```
$stick; // is a multidimensional array generated by query

var_dump($stick); // dumps the right multidimensional array values - query working

// send the var to the function
add_action('wp_ajax_foo', function() use ($stick) {
  my_ajax_foo_handler($stick);
});

// send the var to the function public
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_foo', function() use ($stick){
  my_ajax_foo_handler($stick);
});


function my_ajax_foo_handler($stick) {

print_r($stick); /// returns null on ajax query console


    wp_die();
}
```

If I manually create an multidimensional array on a variable before the code it works.

```
 $stick = array (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
); // if I manually enter the array the value is passed successfully.

        var_dump($stick); // dumps the right multidimensional array values - non query version
        
        // send the var to the function
        add_action('wp_ajax_foo', function() use ($stick) {
          my_ajax_foo_handler($stick);
        });
        
        // send the var to the function public
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_foo', function() use ($stick){
          my_ajax_foo_handler($stick);
        });
        
        
        function my_ajax_foo_handler($stick) {
        
        print_r($stick); /// returns the multidimensional array on console.
        
        
            wp_die();
        }
```

I've tried the following :

1. `json_encode` - The computer generated array is also null on `json_encode`.
2. printing a value of the automated array - `var_dump` shows the string- still null on the console ajax request.

I know USE params are early binding but the value of $stick is assigned before the lambda function is declared in each case.

Comment: 1. Are you sure both var_dump($stick); lines output the same array? Can you add those 2 var_dump outputs to your question? 2. Where does $stick; value come from in the first block? Which query generates it?

Comment: @ElvinHaci I think I know what's causing the problem. When I set a static value, it registers in the query correctly. If there is any computation to retrieve the value, the query triggers before the computed value is assigned to the variable. I'm actually not supposed to be able to return any php information to wp_ajax but this almost works anyway... oh well.

Comment: Then try using $GLOBALS['stick'] everywhere, instead of $stick.